# send an email to my gmail address with django in cpanel server

Tags: python, django, email, cpanel

I have a Cpanel server which runs a Django app, and I have a form in my website that I want erverytime an anonymous user has filled the form a new email send to my Gmail address, I dont know the best practice to implement this scenario

Comment: have you tried googling? this question is waaaaay to broad for on here...

Comment: I think this Django documentation related to sending emails (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/#module-django.core.mail) would be a great starter for you.